# Giraph and Cassandra

Tags: giraph

Did anybody try to use Giraph and DSE Cassandra?

I try to run but process hangs:

> 14/10/21 16:38:24 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201410211229_0028>
>
> 14/10/21 16:38:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 80% reduce 0%

Command line is:

> dse hadoop jar
> /usr/local/giraph/giraph-examples/target/giraph-examples-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar
> org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner -D giraph.zkList=SRVITSD03:22181
> org.apache.giraph.examples.SimpleShortestPathsComputation  -vif
> org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat
> -vip /user/hduser/input/tiny_graph.txt -vof org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat -op
> /user/rav/giraph/output/shortestpaths -w 4

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved.
I needed to modify code and add timeout.